# Use Google Maps Api Event/Listener in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

ok. what i want is the following: i want to control a mouseover of a marker with jquery.

how can i do that? i have no experience with pure js. (and i don't want to use a jquery-plugin)

i tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'ggmouseover', function() {
            marker.setIcon(pinred);
        });

        ggmouseover.mouseover();
```

this does not work. (it works with 'mouseover' instead of 'ggmouseover') i want to create a function or something i can call later through jquery.
like: `$('#button').mouseover(function(){ ggmouseover(); });`

how can i do this? ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using :

[`trigger(instance:Object, eventName:string, var_args:*)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event)

> Triggers the given event. All arguments after eventName are passed as arguments to the listeners.

Which gives, for your case :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.setIcon(pinred);
});

$("#button").mouseover(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');
});
```

Comment: Can I also write 'somethingelse' instead of 'mouseover' so that the mouseover only happens with the jquery-button?